# TypeError: Cannot create property 'cacheGroups' on boolean 'false'

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

I want to create a "sentry" chunk file in next.config.js.

I tried to implement like following in `next.config.js`:

```
webpack(config, { isServer }) {
    config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups = {
        ...config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups,
        'sentry': {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](@sentry)[\\/]/,
            name: '@sentry',
            priority: 10,
            reuseExistingChunk: false,
        },
    };

    return config;
}
```

When I try to run the application it is showing this error:

`TypeError: Cannot create property 'cacheGroups' on boolean 'false'`

How can I create a chunk in nextjs with webpack custom configuration?

Thanks